# Yii2 Login by calling stored process

Tags: php, authentication, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a fairly unique problem. I'm using a Yii2 web stack with external SAS components. I'm also currently using openLDAP for authentication with SAS and AWS. We manage users and user roles with SAS, so we need to use SAS to log in to the web stack.

That's a little background. Here's the problem: our current stored SAS process takes a username/password and if authenticated, sends back an object containing the user's role for rbac, and the user's full name for use in the interface. This info is not persistent anywhere like in a database, so I'm not sure how to proceed through the login process. The User model by default has a private static $users array, and I've tried adding the formatted string returned by the stored process to this array, but when the login process completes, I get a `null` returned by the `Yii::$app->user->identity` echo.

This probably sounds a little convoluted, and I'm happy to clarify anything that doesn't make sense.

LoginForm.php

```
namespace app\models;

use app\components\SAS_Auth;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;
    private $_authenticateUser = false;
    public $_authString;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePasswordSas()
            ['password', 'validatePasswordSas'],
        ];
    }

    public function validatePasswordSas($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUserSas();

            $this->_authenticateUser = new SAS_Auth(); // SAS authentication class that contains auth functions
            $this->_authString = $this->_authenticateUser->authenticate($this->username, $this->password);

            if (!$user || !$this->_authString) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    public function loginSas()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUserSas(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getUserSas()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_authenticateUser = new SAS_Auth();
            $this->_authString = $this->_authenticateUser->authenticate($this->username, $this->password);
            $this->_user = User::findIdentity($this->_authString);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

User.php

```
public $id;
public $username;
public $password;
public $authKey;
public $accessToken;

private static $users = [
//        '100' => [
//            'id' => '100',
//            'username' => 'admin',
//            'password' => 'admin',
//            'authKey' => 'test100key',
//            'accessToken' => '100-token',
//        ],
//        '101' => [
//            'id' => '101',
//            'username' => 'demo',
//            'password' => 'demo',
//            'authKey' => 'test101key',
//            'accessToken' => '101-token',
//        ],
];


/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return isset(self::$users['100']) ? new static(self::$users['100']) : null;
}
```

The User model is basically boilerplate. Any direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Check your User model for "public function getId()", it is the implemetation of "yii\web\IdentityInterface", this id is actually used for "findIdentity()".

Answer (score 1):

First tip take a look at the advanced yii2 template, it shows the login process a lot clearer: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/models/LoginForm.php and https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/models/User.php.

Afterwards take a step back and figure what the function purpose is.

The findIdentity in the User actually brings the user details back. In the basic
template from an array, in the advanced template from a db, in your case from LDAP. Just make an ldap_search to get back the details. I personally added to it a little more code to figure out the role based on groups.

The RBAC you are overthinking it, you should have permissions and roles already defined, you just need to figure out what that user role is and assign it for that role. Do this after the login, make sure you remove all previous roles before or you will get an error.

In your case the User::findIdentity will always return null (because probably you are never calling it with 100), you are not able to login anybody in so user->identity will always be null.

I have some LDAP code already at home, I will see if I remember to bring it is tomorrow but the idea is exactly what I told you.